# Switched my running cell to markdown during code run

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have been running a model for the past 24h (optimization of Neural Network parameters by Gaussian process). Tonight, haven't waked up properly form, I hand accidentally switched the cell to markdown and the layout disappeared. Anyway, the code is still running but I don't if the rest of the cells would execute correctly. I like you to tell me if the remaining cells would run as attended or if I should stop and start the whole notebook over again?

[image: Notebook]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this morning the process was over and the code ran perfectly well. So, switching the jupyter notebook cell from code to markdown does not affect the remaining cells and their execution.